# mounting problem

Tags: mount, startup, fstab

Hey I got this problem on my fresh xubuntu 13.10 install

I have a Data device */dev/sda5* which I like to auto-mount it on startup, I added it to the */etc/fstab* file

```
UUID=261ff894-502a-4b5b-8bc7-b53a8ab8e325 /home/linuxer/DATA/   ext4    rw      0       0
```

The problem is that when the I login and access the folder it's **empty!**
Although when I echo the command

```
mount
```

it says that */dev/sda5* is mounted at */home/linuxer/DATA/* !

So I have to unmount it, and it displays:

```
umount: /home/linuxer/DATA: not mounted
```

but on remount, it displays well!


I've got another line in my */etc/fstab*

```
UUID=208A8DE78A8DBA34   /media/win7onsada3      ntfs    rw      0       0
```

and this one works just fine.. It auto-mounts on startup



I have my system set -up with LVM support activated.
Any help would be appreciated!

---

output of *blkid*

```
/dev/sda1: LABEL="Recovery" UUID="CC0E4D840E4D6892" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda2: LABEL="System Reserved" UUID="F43C763F3C75FD44" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda3: UUID="208A8DE78A8DBA34" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda5: LABEL="Data" UUID="261ff894-502a-4b5b-8bc7-b53a8ab8e325" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda6: UUID="42de199a-60ae-48f4-93e0-1d9cb79b93a1" TYPE="ext2" 
/dev/sda7: UUID="gfZ1YH-J0nl-b3l2-uXsA-7Gib-HXWf-6LLX2w" TYPE="LVM2_member" 
/dev/mapper/Distros-ROOTDIR: UUID="ddce62f6-1acb-4878-a079-cc50bb7bc18d" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/mapper/Distros-HOME: UUID="96bda727-1db2-4513-be08-a79e09fe350e" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1: UUID="f6f1556b-d3d2-480e-b3a1-07a79335fa4e" TYPE="swap"
```

output of *cat /etc/fstab*

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/Distros-ROOTDIR /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=42de199a-60ae-48f4-93e0-1d9cb79b93a1 /boot           ext2    defaults        0       2
/dev/mapper/Distros-HOME /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
/dev/mapper/Distros-SWAP none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0

#/home/linuxer/Data
UUID=261ff894-502a-4b5b-8bc7-b53a8ab8e325 /home/linuxer/Data/   ext4    defaults,user   0   2
# windows
UUID=208A8DE78A8DBA34   /media/win7onsada3  ntfs    rw  0   0
```

---

output of *lsblk*

```
NAME                       MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda                          8:0    0 698.7G  0 disk  
├─sda1                       8:1    0  14.1G  0 part  
├─sda2                       8:2    0   100M  0 part  
├─sda3                       8:3    0   200G  0 part  /media/win7onsada3
├─sda4                       8:4    0     1K  0 part  
├─sda5                       8:5    0   300G  0 part  
├─sda6                       8:6    0   250M  0 part  /boot
└─sda7                       8:7    0 184.2G  0 part  
  ├─Distros-SWAP (dm-0)    252:0    0     5G  0 lvm   
  │ └─cryptswap1 (dm-3)    252:3    0     5G  0 crypt [SWAP]
  ├─Distros-ROOTDIR (dm-1) 252:1    0    10G  0 lvm   /
  └─Distros-HOME (dm-2)    252:2    0    95G  0 lvm   /home
sr0                         11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

Comment: edit your question and post the output of `sudo blkid` and `cat /etc/fstab`.

Comment: Done! output added.

Comment: I'm confused with your Dat and Data, dat and Data.. :P Also post the output of `sudo lsblk`

Comment: Hope it's less confusing now ;)  Done! output added.

Comment: Ok! Give me some time..

Comment: Have you tried using `defaults` instead of `rw` in your `/etc/fstab`?

Comment: Yes I did @edwin, I used defaults,auto,user ... same problem!

Comment: One reply I got on the Google+ community suggests this:"I think the issue is your encrypted partitions are being mounted after the unencrypted ones. Hence even though DATA is mounted the home over rides it." What do you guys think about it?

Answer (score 3):

**So the last command shows that your /dev/sda5 partition is not mounted**

I don't know what steps did you follow.
 Let us try to mount it again. So please follow these steps.

1. First unmount all the partitions by:

   ```
   sudo umount -a
   ```
2. Then make a directory `Data` under `/home/linuxer`. If already such directory then first remove it,then create:

   ```
   sudo mkdir /home/linuxer/Data
   ```
3. Give the permission `777` to the directory `Data`. You can change the permission according to your need:

   ```
   sudo chmod -R 777 /home/linuxer/Data
   ```
4. Now edit the file `/etc/fstab`. So open in any text editor with root permission and do the changes.

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/fstab
   ```

   Then remove the line:

   ```
   UUID=261ff894-502a-4b5b-8bc7-b53a8ab8e325 /home/linuxer/DATA/   ext4    rw  0   0
   ```

   and add this:

   ```
   UUID=261ff894-502a-4b5b-8bc7-b53a8ab8e325 /home/linuxer/Data    ext4 errors=remount-ro 0       1
   ```

   Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to close, when prompt to save press <kbd>Y</kbd>.
5. Now mount all the partitions using this command:

   ```
   sudo mount -a
   ```

Reply if something goes wrong. Your partition should mount automatically when you reboot your system.

Comment: Nope... Same problem! I can remount but it doesn't go automaticly on reboot!

Comment: That is why I tested it first before giving the answer. It is working fine for me. I don't know what wrong in your case. Ok last try to change the mount point from `/home/linuxer/Data` to `/media/Data` by following same steps. You need to create the directory `Data` under `/media/` and also have to change the file `/etc/fstab` Reply..

Answer (score 1):

Since your /home is on pass 2 it may not be available as a mount-point when it tries to mount your DATA partition. Either specify pass 3 to the DATA partition or mount the DATA on /data and make a symlink from your home directory.

Comment: !! Does the 3rd pass even exist?  BTW, symlinks will cause me many troubles because many configs on the _sda5_ require hard links :/

Answer (score 0):

From man fstab:

> The  mountall(8) program that mounts filesystem during boot also recognises additional options that the  ordinary  mount(8)  tool  does  not.  These  are:  ...  and  ``showthrough'' which  permits  a mountpoint to be mounted before its parent mountpoint (this latter should be used carefully, as it can cause boot hangs).